# Убрать отступы у графика Highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts, css

Добрый день!

Использую библиотеку для построения графиков Highcharts.
Подскажите, как через апи или правкой кода сделать, чтобы кривые графика начинались и заканчивались без отступов? Здесь на примере http://www.highcharts.com/demo/areaspline у кривых слева и справа отступы по 60px.

Пример моего графика: http://jsfiddle.net/nkro6kwr/

Comment: Вот тут нету отступов: [http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-ajax][1]


  [1]: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-ajax

Comment: Хорошо, что там нет. Но нужно сделать именно в типе графика areaspline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

За это отвечает опция "pointPlacement" :

> ```
> plotOptions: {
>     series: {
>         pointPlacement: 'on'
>     }            
> },
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Вот тут столкнулись с таким-же вопросом: [`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991486/`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991486/)

Решили вот так:

```
xAxis: {
    min: 0.5, max: 5.5
...
```

где max = количество точек данных минус 1.5

[`http://jsfiddle.net/nkro6kwr/1/`](http://jsfiddle.net/nkro6kwr/1/)